# Response is not available in this context in asax file

Tags: c#

I have a login page that works only with Firefox. It does not work with any other browsers.

When I checked the event log, I saw a "response is not available in the current context". It tells me that the error is in the global.asax file, at the response.redirect line:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?li=1");
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}
```

What could be the problem?

I have tried httpcontext.Current as suggested but then I get a Null Reference Exception, Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HttpContext.Current.Response` it should definitely work.

Comment: It doesn't. HttpContext.Current.Response is null inside Session_End.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using HttpContext.Current.Response?

Happy coding!!

Comment: I tried this but this is throwing NullReferenceException, i am stuck