# How can I tell if Request/Response is available in Application_Error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If `Application_Error` is triggered by an exception in the application start up i.e. `RouteConfig`or `BundleConfig` how can you check if the `Request`/`Response` is available? Currently the call to `Response.Clear` throws `System.Web.HttpException` with additional information `Response is not available in this context`.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Log error
    Log.Error(e);

    //Clear
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    //Redirect
    Response.Redirect("~/Error");
}
```

Other questions suggest rewriting to not use `Response` or to use [`HttpContext.Current.Response`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652006/response-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-asax-file) or changing [IIS config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context?lq=1).

In summary; how can I tell if the error has occurred during app start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to check whether it is **HttpException**.

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Log error
    LogException(exception);

    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        Response.Redirect("~/Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: So will every exception thrown during a request result in a `HttpException`?

Comment: @RDay No it will not. This answer is not helpful.